# UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES IVY APACHE POI 3.13

Tags: ant, apache-poi, ivy

Not able to resolved the IVY dependencies for Apache POI version 3.13

```
<dependencyorg="org.apache.poi"name="poi"rev="3.13"/>
<dependencyorg="org.apache.poi"name="poi-ooxml"rev="3.13"/>
<dependencyorg="org.apache.poi"name="poi-ooxml-schemas"rev="3.13-beta1"/>



<dependencyorg="org.apache.poi"name="poi"rev="3.13"/>
<dependencyorg="org.apache.poi"name="poi-ooxml"rev="3.13"/>
<dependencyorg="org.apache.poi"name="poi-ooxml-schemas"rev="3.13-beta1"/>
```

In Local, IVY is able to download the Apache POI jars, But when in jenkins build it is failing.? May i know why.?

```
    <dependencyorg="org.apache.poi"name="poi"rev="3.13"/>
    <dependencyorg="org.apache.poi"name="poi-ooxml"rev="3.13"/>
    <dependencyorg="org.apache.poi"name="poi-ooxml-schemas"rev="3.13-beta1"/>

==== local: tried
[ivy:resolve]     /app/cp/.ivy2/local/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.13-beta1/ivys/ivy.xml
[ivy:resolve]     -- artifact org.apache.poi#poi-ooxml-schemas;3.13-beta1!poi-ooxml-schemas.jar:
[ivy:resolve]     /app/cp/.ivy2/local/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.13-beta1/jars/poi-ooxml-schemas.jar


::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.poi#poi;3.13: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.poi#poi-ooxml;3.13: not found
[ivy:resolve]       :: org.apache.poi#poi-ooxml-schemas;3.13-beta1: not found
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade to something modern and supported?

Comment: It looks like you don't have this artifact locally installed. Try adding maven central as a remote repository. It definitely exists remotely: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.13-beta1

Comment: I am not using the above repository URL to resolve the poi dependencies.So due to this i got the error like un-resolved dependencies.

Comment: I have updated the correct version that is already available in the repository, now it is working as i expected.